# What makes this first and second paragraph float to the left?

Tags: html, css

```css
#content{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
}

#title {
  display:block;
}

      #name {
        display:block;
      }
      #email {
        display:block;
      }
      
      #number {
        display:block;
      }
```

```html
 <body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="title"><p>This is a survey form.</p></div>
    <div id="description"><p>It would be nice if you  could fill this information about addiction.</p></div>
    <form id="survey-form">
      <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label><input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
      <label id="number-label" for="age">Enter your age:</label>
      <input id="number" type="number" name="age" min="18" max="55" placeholder="Enter your age">
      <h4>What are you currently addicted to?</h4>
      <select id="dropdown" name="items">
        <option value="alcohol">Alcohol</option>
        <option value="smoking">Smoking</option>
        <option value="gaming">Gaming</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
      <p>For how long you've been addited?</p>
      
      <label><input type="radio" name="1month" id="1month"> >1 Month</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="6months" > >6 Months</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="12months" > >12 Months</label><br>
      How many people do you know that are addicted as well?
      <input type="checkbox" value="none">None
      <input type="checkbox" value="few">Few (1-5)
      <input type="checkbox" value="tons">A lot (over 5)
      <p>If there's anything else you would like to point out feel free to do it.</p>
      <textarea name="feedback" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit your information">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

What makes this first and second paragraphs on the page display on the left side?
I've covered everything in div container, but right now as you can see it floats to the left side for some reason.
I would like it to be centered just like the rest of the stuff.
Is using flexbox is a bad option here or something?

Comment: The `content` div has `display: flex`. This means that all direct children will line up adjacently, barring any additional properties that might make them behave differently.

Comment: So it will be better if I use css grid over here?

Comment: While there are certainly ways to achieve centered-stacking with grid or flexbox, I personally feel that you're better off not using any sort of positioning model to achieve such a design. Block elements want to stack vertically by default, meaning all you'd have to do is add some CSS to center them. If you go with flex or grid for the sole purpose of centering something, you're going to override most of their behavioral properties simply to return block level elements to the behavior that they already have by default.

Comment: if you remove display flex it will self align

Answer (score 0):

```css
#content{
  display:grid;
  justify-content:center;
  height:500px;
  width:100%;
}

#title {
  display:block;
}

      #name {
        display:block;
      }
      #email {
        display:block;
      }
      
      #number {
        display:block;
      }
      input#submit{
      display:block;
      }
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="title"><p>This is a survey form.</p></div>
    <div id="description"><p>It would be nice if you  could fill this information about addiction.</p></div>
    <form id="survey-form">
      <label id="name-label" for="name">Name:</label><input id="name" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
      <label id="email-label" for="email">Email:</label>
      <input id="email" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email">
      <label id="number-label" for="age">Enter your age:</label>
      <input id="number" type="number" name="age" min="18" max="55" placeholder="Enter your age">
      <h4>What are you currently addicted to?</h4>
      <select id="dropdown" name="items">
        <option value="alcohol">Alcohol</option>
        <option value="smoking">Smoking</option>
        <option value="gaming">Gaming</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
      <p>For how long you've been addited?</p>
      
      <label><input type="radio" name="1month" id="1month"> >1 Month</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="6months" > >6 Months</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="12months" > >12 Months</label><br>
      How many people do you know that are addicted as well?
      <input type="checkbox" value="none">None
      <input type="checkbox" value="few">Few (1-5)
      <input type="checkbox" value="tons">A lot (over 5)
      <p>If there's anything else you would like to point out feel free to do it.</p>
      <textarea name="feedback" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit your information">
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: i changed flex to grid but if you want you can remove display grid and give #content a margin-left: 40 or 50%  i hope this help

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can help you achieve what you are looking for. You can replace your CSS code with the below snippet.

```
#content{
    text-align:center;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
#title {
    display:block;
}
#name {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#email {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
#number {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```